# How does one understand geometric CFT in terms of modularity?

Tags: nt.number-theory, class-field-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, adeles

I have recently asked a question in a similar vein:
[What makes Geometric CFT easier than CFT?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100798/what-makes-geometric-cft-easier-than-cft)

but I'm afraid I wasn't quite ripe to ask it yet. I have since consulted with the following sources:

http://jmilne.org/math/Books/ADTnot.pdf,
[http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/249BPage/handouts/geomcft.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/249BPage/handouts/geomcft.pdf)
and
http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512172

As well as some sources refreshing my memory on classic CFT:

http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gounelas/projects/bmo.pdf
and
[http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~trs/expository-papers/tex/CFT.pdf](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/%7Etrs/expository-papers/tex/CFT.pdf)
among others.

My motivation for studying geometric class field theory was first and foremost to solidify my understanding of classic class field theory. I thought that perhaps the geometric intuition will shed some light on the rather massive apparatus of CFT.

In order to be concrete, I will specify a version of geometric CFT:

Theorem A: Let $C$ be a smooth projective, geometrically irreducible curve over a finite field $k$, and let $K$ be its function field. Then the (Artin reciprocity) map $\Phi_K:Div(C)\rightarrow \pi_1^{ab}(C)$ given by $p\mapsto Frob_p$ factors through $Pic(C)$, and induces an isomorphism between the profinite completion of $Pic(C)$ and $\pi_1^{ab}(C)$.

This appears in Toth's master thesis (linked above) as Theorem 1.1.4. In order to understand this as analogous to classic CFT, one need only notice that $K^{\times}\backslash \mathbb{I}_K/ \prod _{p \mbox{ closed point in } C}\hat{O_p} $ (where $\mathbb{I}_K$ is the ideles, and $\hat{O_p}$ is the completion of the stalk at the closed point $p$) is isomorphic to $Pic(C)$.

In other words the theorem above can be viewed as analogous to the adelic point of view of CFT (i.e. the isomorphism between the profinite completions of $K^{\times}\backslash \mathbb{I}_K/\prod_v O_v^{\times}$ with $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$, where $K$ is a number field). I am interested in understanding what the analogous picture in Geometric CFT to modular formulations (rather than adelic ones) of classic CFT.

#### Question

How does one understand geometric CFT (as described in the theorem above) in terms of modularity results? In other words, what is the analogous statement to the fact that (up to finitely many primes) the splitting of primes in an abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is determined by what those primes are conjugate to modulo some conductor? Is there a geometric intuition behind the analogous statement in geometric CFT?

#### EDIT

After reading the comments carefully, and going back to my old notes on Class Field Theory to refresh my mind about a few things that I got wrong in the comments, I have come to the conclusion that the following is the question that I really wanted to ask:

We have:

Theorem B: or $K$ a number field, we have that $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$ is isomorphic to the profinite completion of $K^{\times}\backslash \mathbb{I}_K/D_K$ where $D_K$ is the connected component of $1$.

Theorem A above is not analogous to Theorem B because, as Felipe pointed out, Theorem A is only about abelian extensions that are unramified, whereas Theorem B allows ramification everywhere. My question is: what is the analogous statement to Theorem A in the Number Theory case?

I am in particular confused by the subtlety regarding the distinction between $D_K$ and the product $\prod _{p \mbox{ closed point in } C}\hat{O_p}$. Are they the same?

Comment: That theorem you cite is only unramified class field theory. To get the full picture you need to allow ramification too.

Comment: @Felipe: I am confused by your statement. The analogous theorem to the theorem I cited in the number theory case describes $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$ in terms of (the profinite completion of) a double quotient of the ideles of $K$. If the theorem I cited is only unramified class field theory, wouldn't it describe $Gal(K^{ab,un}/K)$ instead? 

Comment: $Gal(K^{ab,un}/K) = \pi_1^{ab}(C)$ because $C$ is projective. 

Comment: In what sense? For example it is not true that every abelian cover of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is unramified! (E.g., $y^2=x$ will define an abelian cover ramified over $0$ and $\infty$.) I feel like I'm missing the crucial point you're trying to get across... Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: The fundamental group only captures unramified covers, by definition. $\pi_1({\mathbb{P}}^1)$ is trivial.

Comment: I'm sorry, my last comment was silly. You're right that $\pi_1^{ab}(C)\cong Gal(K^{ab,un}/K)$. My question is, why is the analogous statement for $K$ a number field that $K^{\times}\backslash \mathbb{I}_K/\prod_v O_v^{\times}$ is isomorphic (after taking profinite completions) to $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$ rather than $Gal(K^{ab,un}/K)$? Or am I wrong about that? For example $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}\backslash \mathbb{I}_{\mathbb{Q}}/\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is far from trivial, isn't it?
I guess I'm just finding it hard to draw the analogy.

Comment: The product $\prod_v O_v^{\times}$ does not include the archimedian places in the number field case. In the function field case, if you exclude a finite set of places you get a bigger group. Read Serre "Groupes algebriques et corps de classes"

Comment: @Felipe: sorry for asking so many questions, but I'm confused again. Serre's book would be easier to read with a little motivation, so hopefully you'll indulge me. My perception was that if $S$ is a finite set of places, then $K^{\times}\backslash \mathbb{I}_K/\prod_{v\not \in S} O^{\times}_v$ would have a profinite completion which is isomorphic to $Gal(L/K)$ where $L$ is the maximal abelian cover of $K$ that is ramified only in $S$. But it seems that what you're saying is that if S is the set of infinite places, then 

Comment: $K^{\times}\backslash \mathbb{I}_K/\prod_{v\not \in S} O^{\times}_v$ is isomorphic to $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$. What is the correct way to think about this? 

Comment: @Makhalan: It is not true that $K^\times \backslash I_K / \prod_\nu O_\nu^\times$ is isomorphic (after taking profinite completions) to $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$, or even $Gal(K^{ab,un}/K)$. Something that is true: $I_K/K^\times$ is a topological group. Call its connected component $D_K$. Then there is an isomorphism $K^\times \backslash I_K/ D_K \cong Gal(K^{ab}/K)$. For example, the group $\mathbb{Q}^\times \backslash I_\mathbb{Q} / \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ is connected, and dividing by itself we can recover the classical fact that the rational field has no unramified extensions.

Comment: It is not that $D_K$ is the product of completions. $D_K$ is some product over the finitely many infinite places. For example, for the rationals, there is an isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}^\times \backslash I_\mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{R}_+^\times \times \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, and the connected component of 1 is $\mathbb{R}_+^\times \times 1$. So $Gal(\mathbb{Q}^{ab}/\mathbb{Q})\cong \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. To get the unramified abelian extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, we further divide by $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, to get $\mathbb{Q}^{ab,un}=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: In general, to get maximal abelian extensions with general controlled ramification, you divide by a similar product over the places of the field. The galois group will be isomorphic to the double cosets, and these groups are finite. Two primes split in the same manner if they give rise to the same double coset. Finally, there is an interpretation of the double cosets as a ray class group, much like a generalised jacobian for a curve (Picard group corresponds to maximal unramified abelian extension). So primes split equivalently if they have the same class in the ray class group.

Comment: @Dror: that's very helpful. Let me ask you a few questions. 1. Is $D_K$ always the product over all infinite places? 2. Let $L$ be the maximal abelian extension of $K$ that is unramified over a specific set of primes $S$ of $O_K$. Are you saying that $L^{\times}N_{L/K}(\mathbb{I}_L)$ is equal to the product $\prod_{\mathfrak{p} \not \in S} O_{\mathfrak{p}} ^{\times}$? I guess what I'm trying to ask is: it seems that you're saying that the "reason" that there are no abelian unramified extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ is that you get $Gal(\mathbb{Q}^{un,ab}/\mathbb{Q})$ by quotienting

Comment: $\mathbb{I}_{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ by $D_{\mathbb{Q}}$, which is the product of the infinite places, and by $\prod \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ (to account for not allow ramification anywhere). But I wonder where you're using something special about $\mathbb{Q}$, because this isn't true for all number fields, is it?

Comment: For a general number field it is not necessarily true that $K^\times \backslash I_K / D_K\prod_v O_v^\times$ is trivial. As you may know, the maximal unramified extension of a number field, called its Hilbert class field, has galois group over the field isomorphic to the class group. I don't remember if there is a small play on the infinite places, but in any case $K^\times\backslash I_K / D_K\prod_v O_v^\times$ is either the class group, or something very close to it (maybe the strict class group). This is all standard CFT, and appears in any CFT book. I highly recommend Milne's online notes.

Comment: What do you mean by "modularity", and what does it have to do with your question?  It seems to be purely a question about geometric class field theory.  The only thing that comes to mind for what you mean is modularity of elliptic curves, but that seems to be entirely unrelated.